# What is stopping this web page from shrinking to fit widths of less than 530 pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to make my site [tokyocomedy.com](http://tokyocomedy.com) to be responsive design down to a minimum of 320 pixels wide. Most, if not all, pages, such as this top page look reasonably good down to that size, using Firefox's responsive design view:

[image: top page with working responsive design]

However, this one page, [the schedule page](http://tokyocomedy.com/schedule), is not working:

[image: schedule page with broken responsive design]

The width it gets stuck at seems to be around 530 pixels:

[image: schedule page 530 pixel width]

The only thing that is different on this page is the calendar, so I could be wrong, but my best guess is that something about the calendar CSS or JavaScript is holding some minimum width or padding space or something. I have gone through all the elements I can find using the Firefox web developer inspector:

[image: inspecting the schedule page]

Relevant CSS IDs and classes seem to be `#calendar, fc-toolbar, fc-header-toolbar, fc-view-container, fc-view, fc-list-month-view, fc-widget-content,` and `fc-widget-header`. However, I can't find any width declarations, padding, margins, or any other sizing declaration that would explain why the page will not shrink horizontally. It's possible that maybe there is JavaScript acting on the styling that is altering it in a way that is less easy to find.

The page uses the [fullcalendar v3.9.0](https://fullcalendar.io/) JavaScript library. I've put the [CSS in use on PasteBin for reference](https://pastebin.com/CFdTbZ54).

**What is preventing this calendar page from shrinking down to 320 pixels like other pages on the site?**

Comment: It’s the really long, unbreakable words …@group.calendar.google.com, combined with `#maincontent` being `display: inline-block`. I can’t tell where you set the maximum width for `#maincontent`, but try making a breakpoint that makes it a `display: block` element when its width is less than the maximum. Then you can apply `word-wrap: break-word` to the `<p>`s, or use a `<wbr />` inside them (e.g. before the @).

Comment: It seems working on chrome.

Comment: @pooyan, it's not so much that it works on Chrome, it's that Chrome has a built in feature to scale the content to the viewport. So, Chrome sees the page is breaking at 530 pixels and then shrinks it to fit.

Comment: @Ry-, thanks for responding. Yes, you're right, it was the long text causing the problem. A little embarrassing, as I was so focused on the calendar that I didn't account for the text length below the calendar. I will apply some form of solution with `word-wrap` as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error in your code. You need to use `word-break` css property here as your email text is big. kindly refer to attached screenshot.

Hope it solves your problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You used display:inline-block style.css line no. 60 ,use display:block rather than display: inline-block

```
#maincontent, #upcomingshows, #recentblog{
 display:block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add below two property and check

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    #maincontent {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```